# IE8 Error Loading Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, internet-explorer-8

I am building a website that uses Google Maps.
When the page loads in IE 8 I get the following error.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; InfoPath.3; Release=ARP)
Timestamp: Tue, 8 Apr 2014 05:08:34 UTC

Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_AU/mapfiles/embed/16/6/init_embed.js

Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_au/mapfiles/api-3/16/6/%7Bmain,search%7D.js

The HTML that tries to display the map is shown below.

```
  <div class="map">
    <iframe width="700" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com.au/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=34+Wilson+St,+Brighton,+Victoria&amp;aq=&amp;sll=-37.911623,144.999827&amp;sspn=0.000435,0.000984&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=34+Wilson+St,+Brighton+Victoria+3186&amp;ll=-37.911606,144.999591&amp;spn=0.003466,0.007875&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com.au/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=34+Wilson+St,+Brighton,+Victoria&amp;aq=&amp;sll=-37.911623,144.999827&amp;sspn=0.000435,0.000984&amp;t=m&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=34+Wilson+St,+Brighton+Victoria+3186&amp;ll=-37.911606,144.999591&amp;spn=0.003466,0.007875&amp;z=14" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>      
  </div>
```

Not sure whats causing this as it seems to work in all other browser types I have tried (Chrome, Firefox, Safari).